# preg_match_all returning arrays

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I recently made a small script to catch any URL's that pass through a textarea based on a form submit.

The regular expression im using is:

```
'/([\w]+).(local|test|stage|live).site.example.com/'
```

and if submit:

```
<p>body</p> <p>uk2.local.site.example.net 
training.test.site.example.net</p>
<p>www.google.com</p>
<p>sd2.test.site.example.net</p>
```

i am returned with an array that contains:

```
0   =>  array(3
  0   =>    uk2.local.site.example.net
  1   =>    training.test.site.example.net
  2   =>    sd2.test.site.example.net
)
1   =>  array(3
  0   =>    local
  1   =>    test
  2   =>    test
)
```

I'm not sure why i get the second array and wanted to look to clean it up.

Comment: It matches the stuff within paranthesis, it is called "subpatterns": http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-capture group, also escape the dots:

```
 '/(\w+)\.(?:local|test|stage|live)\.site\.example\.com/'
 // here __^^
```